# Real-time screen capture and feature detection using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I successfully processed a video and had the algorithm detect faces, but I am attempting to detect faces in real-time, capturing images from the screen (such as when I'm playing games, etc.) This is the bit of the code I used to process a captured video:

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('source_video.avi')
```

How can I change this to capture images from the screen in real-time? Please give me some code examples if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use openCV for this. Better use

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
ImageGrab.grab().save("screen_capture.jpg", "JPEG")
```

Comment: But that'd be saving the screen to a file, which would be extremely slow. Is it possible in real-time, even if it is at a slow rate of 1 frame per second? And how do I achieve feature detection without OpenCV? I apologize in advance for the stupid questions...

Comment: No need to save it. You can just keep it in memory

Comment: Would ImageGrab and processing the grabbed image then be theoretically faster than attempting to processing the video?